# How to pass workitem id of RTC tool to web application in java

Tags: java, jsp, rational-team-concert

I have created a web application using jsp servlet and integrated with IBM RTC work items by providing static link of web application.
I have to pass RTC Work item id to web application at runtime.
So whenever user click on the static link of particular work item that work item id should pass to web application.
Kindle guide me.

Comment: What kind of RTC link are you providing? OSLC (JSON/XML) or just view link? Can you elaborate? Question is not clear.